# Removing from the List and the use of API

Tags: c#, .net, api

I am trying to make a program where permit's needs to be deleted from the user account. API's are used to pull up the user account and the permits. After the permits and restrictions are removed an event is created to confirm the deletion. Right now it's not giving me any output what so ever.

```
String User;
String License;
List<String> Permit;
public RemovePermit(String User, String license, List<String> Permit)
{
    this.User = user;
    this.License = license;
    this.Permit = Permit;
}

public void Run()
{
    List<PPermitGroups> permitGroupAdd = new List<PPermitGroups>();
    using (var apiUser = new ApiUser())
    {
        var user = apiGetPerson(User);
        var userPermit = apiGetPermitGroup(user.ID);
        String license = License;
        var deletePermitResult = userPermit.Where(x => Permit.Any(l => x.PermitGroup.Equals(l)|(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Company)&& x.Company.Equals(l))));

        foreach (PPermitGroups p in deletePermitResult)
        {
            apiDeletePermitAndRestrictions(p);

            if(p.PermitGroupType == PPermitGroupsPermitGroupTypeEnum.ApplicationPermit)
            if (p.LicenseType.Equals("Not Fixed") || p.LicenseType.Equals("Fixed"))
                if (p.PermitGroup.StartsWith("Framework") || p.PermitGroup.StartsWith("Release"))
                {
                   var temp =  new UserEvent
                   EventType= " Delete"
                    License= ""
                    Permit = ""
            }
          api.CreateEvent(temp)
```

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here to help you. When you say "it's not giving me any output" do you mean you aren't getting events raised? i.e. `apiDeletePermitAndRestrictions(p);` is being called but the `apiCreateUserEvents(temp3)` line is not being hit when you expect it to? You have three levels of nested ifs that guard this code: you'll have to debug this and step through why your objects are failing these checks, either using breakpoints and a debugger or logging out all of these properties of the objects and whether an event was raised or not.

Comment: So when I run the script it not deleting any permits what so ever and yes event api is not hit as well.

Comment: OK, then you'll have to work out whether deletePermitResult is wrong or empty, and so the bug is in the lines that fetch apiGetPermitGroup and filter them down, or if you are getting the permits here that you want to delete but that apiDeletePermitAndRestrictions isn't working.

Comment: You've used `|` for 'or' in your deletePermitResult test. It's usually `||` for the boolean shortcut 'or' as you've used in the if tests. But I can't see that this would make a difference here.

Comment: Yea, I think you are right, its not even reading the permit groups which means if there are no permits then how in the world is it going to delete it :/

Comment: Can you tell me why Event and work info isnt working?